# How to install kubernetes cluster on Rancher cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Use Rancher server on several servers:

- Master
- Node1
- Node2
- Node3

Maybe only need rancher agent on node servers.

Also want to make kubernetes cluster on these servers. So install Kubernetes master on Rancher master, install Kubernetes nodes(kubelet) on Rancher nodes. Is it right?

So, the Kubernetes nodes can't install using Rancher server but should do it by self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Rancher Agent on any server you want Rancher to place containers on. Rancher can deploy Kubernetes for you. I believe what you want to do is add all of the nodes, including the Rancher master, to a single Cattle environment(The Default env is Cattle). When adding the Rancher Server make sure you set CATTLE_AGENT_IP=. Once the hosts are registered, you will want to set host labels on the nodes. For nodes 1,2,3 you will set the label `compute=true`. On the Rancher Server you will set host 2 host labels, `etcd=true` and `orchestration=true`.

Once the labels are set up. Click on Catalog and search for Kubernetes. You can probably stick with most defaults, but CHANGE `plane isolation` to `required`.

Rancher should deploy Kubernetes management servers on the same host as your Rancher Server and the remaining nodes will be Kuberenetes minions.

Comment: Thank you very much. You understand my meaning very well. That's what I want! Now I will start to try your method above and hope have lucky. If have trouble, maybe leave message here again. Have a good day.

Comment: By the way, I want to ask an another question. If I want to install other cluster management tools, such as docker swarm/mesos, is the config above is common method?